# I have a file with all the iptable settings. How do I load this into my server?

Tags: unix

My system admin gave me a file with iptables rules.
What command do I type in to load this?

I heard people can do this in one line?

Something like...iptables > thefile.dat ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save your current iptables using iptables-save as in

```
iptables-save >thefile.dat
```

and later load it with

```
cat thefile.dat | iptables-restore
```

Comment: Umm, why use `cat` instead of simply `iptables-restore < thefile.dat`?

Comment: Out of habit, no other reason.